# Check URL and stop processing using htaccess

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to check URL using htaccess. Developer might want run special file - specialfile.php. I use htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /specialfile\.php$
RewriteRule .* [L]   #don't change adress
RewriteRule ^$ public/index.html [NC,L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [NC,L]
```

My idea was: if rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/specialfile.php$  true than htaccess should use RewriteRule .* [L] - that should mean that specialfile.php will be run and this all. But it doesn't work because it runs next rule: RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [NC,L].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using the `RewriteCond` not correctly. The conditions only affect the next `RewriteRule` that follows.

Check out [the example on the Apache Homepage](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond). Since your 2nd `RewriteRule` is evalutated, I think your conditions are not correct. To get a litte bit more information about the rewriting, you should increase the log level. This [is also documented here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog).

Your 2nd rule `^$` matches only an empty request btw. That's why it probably does not work as you expect it to.